# combine row groups within time range

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am facing a problem in a query and I am stuck for quite some time now. Here the situation: I have a table with certain records in it, which are terminated via ValidFrom and ValidTo. This table tracks data changes of another table - everytime the underlying data changes, the last valid record is terminated and an insert is performed. Following a SQL fiddle example:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/15c7f/4/0

What I try to achieve is to group records with identical Flags within a timespan into one record. In my fiddle ecample: I would expect the first two records being combined to one record with ValidFrom 2017-01-01 and ValidTo 2017-01-10.

Anyways, I am severly stuck and I tried numerous approaches I found here and in another forum - but without success. One approach is included in the fiddle: evaluate the rownumber ordered by date and substract the rownumber partitioned by flag columns etc. ... but nothing works out.

[image]

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: `group records with identical Flags within a timespan` - specify what timespan?

Comment: See the fiddle for examples: e.g. 2017-01-01 - 2017-01-05 and 2017-01-06 - 2017-01-10 should be combined to one record, since Flag1 and Flag2 are identical. 2017-01-20 - 2017-01-21 and 2017-01-22 - 2017-01-27 as well. But: 2017-01-28 - 2017-02-01 should get a new group - even if it has the same flags as the first two records - since it's a separate timerange and does not directly follow the first two rows

Comment: Can you post your output please ?

Comment: It's in the fiddle as well... I added it to the OP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this query:

```
select keycol, min(validfrom), max(validto), flag1, flag2 from
(
select *,
       sum(iscontinuation) over (partition by keycol order by validfrom rows between UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) [GroupingCol]
from (
  select *,
         case when
         lag(validto) over (partition by keycol order by validfrom) = dateadd(day, -1, validfrom) and
         lag(flag1) over (partition by keycol order by validfrom) = flag1 and
         lag(flag2) over (partition by keycol order by validfrom) = flag2 then 0
         else 1 end [IsContinuation]
   from t
) a
) b group by keycol, flag1, flag2, groupingcol
```

Comment: IMHO this 'solution' simply fuses the first two records. Check this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/60dbe/2 It produces a single row, however, it should produce two distinct rows!

Comment: @MichałTurczyn Hello thx again. But I found another glitch in the query: e.g. when there are several records in row with identical flags (yes, unfortunately it happens in the source system), your query will no longer work as expected. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d7613/2/0 for details

Comment: @MichałTurczyn Thanks again. Seemingly it works now - after a small modification: I had to replace `[PARTITION BY (SELECT NULL) ] ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)` with `PARTITION BY KeyCol ORDER BY ValidFrom` - maybe you could clarify, why you chose `SELECT NULL`instead?

Comment: @Tyron78 Of course. In `over` clause you need to specify partitioning and ordering. You don't have any partition, that's why I have written `partition by (select NULL)` (it means no partitioning). But partitioning by `keyCol` may be better solution, since I worked only on subset of your table. Ordering - similairly, we wanted to preserve default ordering of the table, so didn't want introduce any ordering, thus `order by (select NULL)`.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn Thanks a lot! This was of great help. :-)

Comment: If you don't want to specify partition, then you can simply omit partition by. "PARTITION BY (SELECT NULL)" is just noise here.

Comment: I would never depend on the order of records in a select without "order by". Even if records are written to the table in a given order (by keyCol,validFrom), there is no guarantee that a select will return those rows in that order. Probably that is why "partition by" is **not** compulsory, but "order by" is **compulsory** in the analytic function's OVER clause.

Comment: With proper order in OVER clause, "rows between UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW" is meaningless. I corrected a few thing (missing keyCol from group by, missing lag(keyCol) in inner part) and put it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2f3ae/63 . Could you please update your answer with it?

Comment: @MichałTurczyn I modified your answer in order to include partitioning etc. - feel free to review / undo my change, but I think it's a bit more complete that way. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use min max with partition by your group.Got some help from Michal' Query . This can handle multiple flag data as well

```
With CTE2 as(
select *,
       (case when flag1 = lag(flag1) over (order by (select null)) and
      flag2 = lag(flag2) over (order by (select null)) then -1 else 0 end) +
      row_number() over (order by (select null)) [GroupingCol]
from t)

Select KeyCol,Flag1,Flag2,ValidFrom,ValidTo From (
Select KeyCol,Flag1,Flag2,
     min(ValidFrom) over (partition by KeyCol,Flag1,Flag2,GroupingCol) ValidFrom ,
     Max(ValidTo) over (partition by KeyCol,Flag1,Flag2,GroupingCol) ValidTo,
     Row_number() over (partition by KeyCol,Flag1,Flag2,GroupingCol order by keycol,ValidFrom) RN
From CTE2) A where RN=1
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the required result: the first record should be terminated at 2017-01-10, since onle flag changes at 2017-01-11. On 2017-01-28 both flags match the first records again, but nevertheless this record is only valid from 2017-01-28 to 2017-02-01.